# cli_dispatch.phpsh: Cli-Script with Extbase repository injection

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

So, I've got a script that is called like this:

```
./cli_dispatch.phpsh varnish_instance_update update 123.4.5.6,45.29.102.3
```

Basically it gets a list of IPs that should be updated in the database.

```
<?php

namespace Bene\VarnishInstanceUpdate\Cli;

if (!defined('TYPO3_cliMode')) {
    die('You cannot run this script directly!');
}

class Updater {

    /**
     * console arguments
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $args;

    /**
     * @var \Mittwald\Varnishcache\Domain\Repository\ServerRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $serverRepository;

    function __construct() {

        $this->args = $_SERVER['argv'];
        $this->clearServers();

    }

    function clearServers() {
        $this->serverRepository->removeAll();
    }

}

$instance = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('\\Bene\\VarnishInstanceUpdate\\Cli\\Updater');
```

Unfortunately this will end with the error 'Fatal error: Call to a member function removeAll() on null'. It's the same with findAll(), count(), add(), etc.

How will I get access to extbase methods? What am I missing?

---

### Edit: (some sort of) solution

Thanks to Jost I got it to work, kinda.

```
<?php

namespace Bene\VarnishInstanceUpdate\Command;
use \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\CommandController;

if (!defined('TYPO3_cliMode')) {
    die('You cannot run this script directly!');
}

class UpdateCommandController extends CommandController {

    /**
     * @var \Mittwald\Varnishcache\Domain\Repository\ServerRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $serverRepository;

    /**
     * Clears the server table
     */
    function clearServersCommand() {
        $this->serverRepository->removeAll();
    }

}
```

In ext_localconf.php

```
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['extbase']['commandControllers'][$_EXTKEY] =
        \Bene\VarnishInstanceUpdate\Command\UpdateCommandController::class;
}
```

You call it like this:

```
./cli_dispatch.phpsh extbase update:clearservers
```

But: removeAll() uses findAll() which needs a storagePid which needs the TypoScript config to work. I guess this a follow up question.

Comment: Just as a hint: get an instance of the configuration manager and use its API to get the ts you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably not getting your `Updater` instance via an [`ObjectManager`](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_object_1_1_object_manager.html), and thus no dependency injection is done.

To fix that, you should implement your script as a [`CommandController`](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_mvc_1_1_controller_1_1_command_controller.html). It works similar to `ActionControllers`, [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/10-Outlook/3-Command-controllers.html) is how to do it. You can then use the script as scheduler task as well as cli script, with automatic argument parsing. For CLI execution check the output of

```
./cli_dispatch.phpsh extbase help
```

to get the list of available tasks and their parameters.

To make working on the CLI easier, you could also use the extension [`typo3_console`](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/typo3_console).